# What is the correct order for setting up custom domain like customer.client.com/portal for Experience Cloud?

Tags: experience-cloud, digital-experience, domain, digital

Should Domain be setup and configured before Digital Experiences are turned on?

Or can Digital Experiences be turned on first an then Domain can be configured?

I feel confused by the prompt

> You can't change your domain name or disable digital experiences after
> you enable them.

[image]

Does that mean that we will not be able to change later Experience Cloud domain from `customer.my.site` to `customer.client.com/portal`

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to enabled Digital Experiences first and then setting up Domain.